# Upgrading to newer kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel 3.13. After a recent update of the kernel, my VMware Player installation stopped working. I would like to upgrade to the newer 3.16 kernel which comes with fresh 14.04.2 installations so I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Then I run the suggested command but it ends up in an error:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 account-plugin-google : Depends: libaccount-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed or
                                  ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5feedback5 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Do you have any Third Party repositories?

Comment: I have MariaDB, LibreOffice 4.4 and Google Earth. Should I disable these?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Comment: It still complains: